# How to execute business objects in a correct order

Tags: database, object, uml

Let's say I have two business objects or entities: person and address. class person, class address

```
Person *-----* Address
```

Now, someone fills out a Web form and enters his personal data (name,surname,street). All data is transferred correctly via a query string to the webserver.

Now, I am wondering how use the business classes and methods to store this data in a correct manner?
Which approach is the right one? And how do I know the right one?

1St option:

```
$person = new Person(name, surname)  
$person.setAddress(street)
$person.saveToDB();  
// within setAdress an instance of Address-Class -> .setAddress(street){new Address(street)}
```

Or

2Nd option:

```
$address = new Address(Street)  
$address.setPerson(name,surname)
$address.saveToDB();   
// within setPerson an instance of Person-Class -> setPerson(name,surename){new Person(name,surname)}
```

How do I know the right order? I'm a bit confused about this!
And how to handle the DB-Insertion, as i melt 2 BOs and have to save it in two different tables in the database? I totally mess up with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your domain. In some domains the address will be owned by the person (for example a shipping system) and in other domains the person will be owned by the address (for example a mapping application). So the correct solution depends on your domain.

Second, there are many orm (object relational mapping) frameworks out there that handle all DB interactions for you. Pick the one that matches your language and taste and use it.

Comment: ok, after a little searching to the ORM topic i finally found my answer on martinflowers architecturel data mapper pattern.... 
thanx for your answer which got me into right direction!